# How can I avoid an Excel cell's being automatically formatted as currency upon entering financial functions such as PV, FV, PMT, NPV...?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cell-format

A cell is automatically formatted as `Currency` when I fill it with a formula including a financial formula like PV, FV, PMT, NPV...
How can I avoid this automatic formatting?

Comment: Format the cells to the desired type prior to entering the formula?  If left as General it will assume you want currency.

Comment: You can also copy all the data after the drop-down formula and paste it as values.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly enough, there is no way to prevent this behavior from Files → Options.
However, as Excel behaves like this only if the cell is formatted as General, you can preformat it in any style except General (i.e., using the Number format) and Excel will not change that format style. This way, you prevent nasty behaviors such as widening the column to fit the currency sign.